# Ruby on rails - model missing required attr_accessor for [RAILS]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I'm using ruby on rails and I have some problem with it !

I tried to create a database but it seems not to work ! 
I generated a model and a database file thank's to the command:

```
rails g model photos
```

And here my codes

**photos_controller.rb :**

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController


  # POST /photos
  # POST /photos.json
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)


photo_controller.rb

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
    end
end
```

**in the model photo.rb :**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
end
```

**in the file 2011234116731_create_photos.rb :**

```
class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration

     def self.up
         add_column :photos, :image_file_name, :string
         add_column :photos, :image_content_type, :string
         add_column :photos, :image_file_size, :string
         add_column :photos, :image_update_at, :string
     end

     def self.down
         remove_column :photos, :image_file_name, :string
         remove_column :photos, :image_content_type, :string
         remove_column :photos, :image_file_size, :string
         remove_column :photos, :image_update_at, :string
     end

end
```

**But when I try to load a page which use an element "image" of the model, I ha the following error :**

Photo model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'
Extracted source (around line #27):

## POST /photos.json

def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
respond_to do |format|
if @photo.save

I noticed that the migration seems not to work because in my scheme.rb : 
( I've done the rake db:migrate command )

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131124183207) do

  create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like the migration ran correctly. And it also doesn't look like a migration that would get generated by the `rails g model` command. It's missing the `create_table` method. It looks like you previously created the Photo model and then created another migration to add the image fields.

My first hunch would be to try rolling the migration back:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=2011234116731
```

Then running `rake db:migrate` again and check your schema file to make sure all the columns are there.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's perfect now !